# Tip calculation - change a number into a decimal represntation

Tags: c, input, calculation

Everything here works the way that I want it to except for the function "tipConvert(tip)".

I want it to change a number, such as 15, into .15 which would be decimal representation of a percentage.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float tipConvert(int tip);

int main()
{   
    char value;
    int intValue tip;
    float bill, result;

    intValue = 1;

    while(intValue == 1)
    {
        printf("Would you like to calculate a tip: y or n?\n");
        scanf("%s", &value);
        if(value == 'y')
        {
            printf("Enter the bill amount:\n");
            scanf("%f", &bill);
            printf("Enter the tip amount as an integer:\n");
            scanf("%i", &tip);
            result = tipConvert(tip)*bill;
            printf("Tip for %.2f is %.2f\n", bill,result);
         }
         else if(value == 'n')
         {
             printf("Thank you for using Tip Calculator.");
             break;
         }
         else
             printf("Please select y or n.\n");

     }
     return 0;
 }

float tipConvert(int tip)
{
    return tip / 100;
}
```

Comment: Please try to make your question titles less generic. What is "the calculation"?

Comment: You are dividint 2 ints; and the result is stored as an int. Therefore, when the result of your division is something like 0.xx, it rounds to zero. Therefore, do tip / 100.0: this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that an int cannot store any decimal numbers, and when calling tip/100, the compiler sees this as an Integer division and returns an int (in your example 0) and casts that to float afterwards.

The easiest way to tell the compiler to use a float division is to divide by a float literal instead of an int literal by using 100.0f. This should fix the division.
Alternatively you can cast tip to float before.

Comment: Of course you could do that, you could also set the parameter to float and pass an int, which is then casted to float.